# Many-to-many relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have three tables

- News
- NewsCategory
- Category

[image]

When I create a new `News` item, I need to assign categories to that new item.

My code looks like that

```
var NewsToSave = new News();
NewsToSave.NewsBody = model.NewsBody;
NewsToSave.NewsTitle = model.NewsTitle;
NewsToSave.NewsImagePath = NewsImagePath;
NewsToSave.NewsDate = System.DateTime.Now;

db.News.Add(NewsToSave);
db.SaveChanges();

foreach (var id in SelectedIDs)
{
    // How to assign selected categories to NewsToSave object and save the Ids in the middle table
}
```

How to assign selected categories to `NewsToSave` object?

Thank you

Comment: in entity framwork only two tables are visiable for you in the navigation properties the mapping table will be managed by EF

Comment: Thanks for your help ...Can you please help me to solve my problem?

Comment: Get all the categories bases on the selected IDs and then do a `NewsToSave.Categories = categories;`. Assuming that you have done the mapping correctly (many to many) EF will populate the third table for you

Answer (score 0):

You could override your context this way:

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<NewsToSave>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Categories).WithMany(i => i.NewsToSaves)
            .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("NewsToSaveID")
                .MapRightKey("CategoryID")
                .ToTable("NewsCategory"));
    }
```

And process the added data:

```
    void AddOrUpdateNews(Context context, int categoryId, string newsTitle)
    {
        var cat = context.Categories.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == categoryId);
        var nws = cat.News.SingleOrDefault(n => n.Title == newsTitle);
        if(nws == null)
        {
            cat.News.Add(context.News.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Title == newsTitle));
        }
    }
```

This worked great on the ASP.NET application I made a few months ago. Hope it can help you out.

Comment: he want add the category to the news your soultion is from the other side he dont want that

Comment: @BassamAlugili I'm assuming he needs both ways for his * to * relation. Otherwish just replace the `cat` query by the actual category.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a category for each id, attach it (provided that it exists in the db already) and then add it to the `Categories` list of the news and save:

```
foreach(var id in SelectedIDs)
{
    var category = new Category { CategoryId == id};
    db.Categories.Attach(category);
    NewsToSave.Add(category);
}

db.News.Add(NewsToSave);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: he just want mapping and not creating a new Category

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var id in SelectedIDs)
{       
// You have to load the category from Db  
var cat = db.Categories.FirstOrDefault(x=> c.Id == id);

// Added to the NewsToSave 
if (cat !=null)
  NewsToSave.Categories.Add(cat);   
}

// Store the changes
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but it's not working .. it gives error

Additional information: Unable to update the EntitySet 'NewsCategory' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation.

Comment: @Lucy Do you have in your DbContext the DbSet<New> News ?

Comment: @Lucy write your entities and the DbContext this is very basic what you need i can help you if you post the code

Comment: @BassamAlugili Might want to edit your first LINQ query `(**c**=> c.Id **=**= id)`